# JavaScript/HTML - Assign a value to selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

The case is basically like this:

I have 2 questions (have to answer both questions):
1. Do you smoke?  a. Yes     b. No
2. Do you drink?  a .Yes     b. No

If the user choose a. in question 1, then value will be 2
If the user choose b. in question 1, then value will be 1
If the user choose a. in question 2, then value will be 2
If the user choose b. in question 2, then value will be 1

After that, I will be sum up the value for selected radio buttons of both questions and display it.

The code for the radio buttons will be:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Do you smoke cigarettes?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="yes1" value="Y" checked="checked">
    <label for="yes1">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="no1" value="N">
    <label for="no1">No</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>Do you drink?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="drink" id="yes2" value="Y" checked="checked">
    <label for="yes2">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="drink" id="no2" value="N">
    <label for="no2">No</label><br><br></li>
</ul>
```

I know that the value in the radio button can be changed but I want to assign value in the javascript function. (The value in the radio button has it's own purpose.)

That's it. Even though I googled it around but still no solution that solve my problem. Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: let me ask you, if select 1->a and 2->b. you want to display 2+1=3 ? is it what you want?

Comment: Why won't you replace `value="Y"` to `value="2"` and `value="N"` to `value="1"` ?

Comment: @iNandi yes, I want that way

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien because my friend is working the value on her part, so I do not want to disturb her progress and anything

Comment: you can use custom attribute. any problem with that?

Comment: @iNandi Is it basically like value = "Y" valueB = "2" ?

Comment: This is the part I'm pretty confused

Comment: the `value` property is simply the actual value of that radio button. That's where you want to store `1` or `2`

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you want. please let me.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Do you smoke cigarettes?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="yes1" data-vale = '2' value="Y" checked="checked">
                <label for="yes1">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
                <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="no1" data-vale = '1' value="N">
                <label for="no1">No</label><br>
            </li>
            <li>Do you drink?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="drink" id="yes2" data-vale = '2' value="Y" checked="checked">
                <label for="yes2">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
                <input type="radio" name="drink" id="no2" data-vale = '1' value="N">
                <label for="no2">No</label><br><br>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" value="Get Value">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
                    var radioValue = $("input[name='smoke']:checked").attr('data-vale');
                    var radioValue2 = $("input[name='drink']:checked").attr('data-vale');
                    console.log( parseInt(radioValue) +parseInt(radioValue2) )
                });

            });

            /*
            * OR if you dont want to change HTML and may be this will work for you
            *
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
                    var radioValue = $("input[name='smoke']:checked").val() == 'Y' ? 2 : 1;
                    var radioValue2 = $("input[name='drink']:checked").val() == 'Y' ? 2 : 1;
                    console.log( parseInt(radioValue) +parseInt(radioValue2) )
                });
            });
            */
        </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yah you can alert it too and store in some global var and use it for future.

Comment: what if I have a decimal number? Is it going to be like: ParseFloat?

Comment: yes, you are right, but I think its parseFloat. Please google it.

Comment: thank you so much, if I have any doubt will be inform you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189049/discussion-between-desmond97-and-inandi).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that i understand you right and i do not now why you want something like this. But this should work

```
<ul>
  <li>Do you smoke cigarettes?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="yes1" value="Y" checked="checked" onchange="yesSelected(this)">
    <label for="yes1">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" id="no1" value="N" onchange="noSelected(this)">
    <label for="no1">No</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>Do you drink?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="drink" id="yes2" value="Y" checked="checked" onchange="yesSelected(this)">
    <label for="yes2">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="drink" id="no2" value="N" onchange="noSelected(this)">
    <label for="no2">No</label><br><br></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function yesSelected(input){
    input.value = 2
    console.log(input.value)
  }
  function noSelected(input){
    input.value = 1
    console.log(input.value)
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you could satisfy this with a script that uses event listeners, specifically the change of value in your radio buttons. 
I would suggest also modeling a simple structure to capture your data. The following could be implemented. Instead of using an id for the question, associate them with an html **data** attribute. In this case we could specify something like **data-question="1"**. It would also be more practical to assign the value you intend to use on the input element from the start. So instead of using value="Y" try value="2" or value="1". Now that we have our html set up we will use another structure, this time to capture the value. We declare a const question of type array that holds objects. Each object represents a question, the id property is the value we associate with the **data-question** attribute on our input. To find the inputs we use the **document.querySelectorAll(selector)** method because two radio buttons share the same attribute. After we simply attach our eventlistener with a handler function that just update our answer for that question. if you wanted to add the result you could use a forEach method on the question const and log it to the console or present it where you find appropriate. Hope this helps

`

```
<ul>
  <li>Do you smoke cigarettes?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" data-question="1" value="2" checked="checked">
    <label for="yes1">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="smoke" data-question="1" value="1">
    <label for="no1">No</label><br>
  </li>
  <li>Do you drink?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="drink" data-question="2" value="2" checked="checked">
    <label for="yes2">Yes</label> &ensp;&ensp;
    <input type="radio" name="drink" data-question="2" value="1">
    <label for="no2">No</label><br><br></li>
</ul>

<script>
const questions = [{id:1, answer:undefined},{id:2, answer: undefined}]

for(current of questions){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-question="'+current.id+'"]');
  for(input of inputs){
    input.addEventListener('change',function(e){ current.answer = e.target.value})
  }
}
</script>
```

`